# finding xpath for an element just below the <body> tag

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I need to find xpath for an element which is not associated with any html tags .Please refer attachment for reference.
I tried to find it using `driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/"));` 
but its  not working,  I need to find text as shown below in image

> 0 records found

through Xpath or any alternative way

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you are interested in is not a part of any element. It is a text node. Selenium doesn't allow you to select a textNode and text node are not actionable also.

So you can get either the page source and check for the presence of `0 records found`. If that what you need to validate. Or you need to get the text using regex

```
(\d+) record found
```

Depending on the language you use you will run that pattern through and get the number from the text

**Edit-1**

Below is a sample code which extract google results, you can customize it to your page

```
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("tarun lalwani");
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();

    String pageData = driver.getPageSource();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("About ([0-9,]+) results");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pageData);

    matcher.find();
    System.out.println("Results: " + matcher.group(1));
```

Comment: 0 records found is just a example case, records are dynamically fetched from last web page and are shown here, so number will be different every time

Comment: That is not a problem you can extract it from the page source, since you are interested in the count

Comment: which language are you using?